# What does writing .fig or .figure at the end of a seaborn plot do?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, data-visualization

I have seen that sometimes to get the desired plot or to do changes in the plot, we need to write .fig or .figure after the plotting function.

For example :

```
p = sns.relplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", data=data, hue="smoker").fig
```

What is the .fig doing?
Also are .fig and .figure doing the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

`sns.replot` returns a `FaceGrid` object which provides tools for manipulating the plot. The `figure` attribute of this object references the matplotlib `Figure` object underlying the plot. The `fig` attribute has the same meaning, but according to the [seaborn documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html#seaborn.FacetGrid) it is deprecated, one should use `figure` instead.